# 0 value column chart - highchart

Tags: highcharts

How do I make a slight shadow or color come up below the x axis for zero valued points in column charts?
Right Now nothing is shown.

Setting the minPointLength property makes a line come up above the x Axis.

Any help or pointers would help.

Below are my options:

```
     plotOptions: {
     column: {
         shadow: false,
         pointWidth: 11.5,
         borderWidth: 0.5,
         enableMouseTracking: false,
         minPointLength: 1
     }
 },
 yAxis: {
     labels: {
         align: 'left',
         style: {
             color: 'gray',
             fontWeight: 'normal',
             fontSize: '8.5px',
             fontFamily: 'Arial'
         }
     },
     minorGridLineWidth: 1,
     minorTickInterval: 10000,
     minorGridLineColor: 'white',
     minorTickWidth: 0,
     title: {
         text: '',
         rotation: 270.0,
         style: {
             fontWeight: 'normal'
         },
         margin: 20,
         style: {
             fontWeight: 'normal',
             fontFamily: 'Arial',
             color: '#666666',
             fontSize: '11px'
         }
     },
     opposite: true,
     min: 0,
     max: 500000,
     tickInterval: 100000,
     gridLineWidth: 0.0
 }
```

This gives me a 1px point above x Axis.
But what I am looking for is a small shadow/1px point below the xAxis.

Comment: Please include a sample of the code you've tried, along with details of why it's not working for you.

Comment: Will be helpful if you paste full code, with your data, because examples like http://jsfiddle.net/dDqBB/ works properly with minPointLength

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found to accomplish something like this is to convert 0 values to negative values (I have most often done something where I have a very small column that goes from -1 to 1, straddling the 0 line)

How large of a spread your data has will determine what negative value you need to specify.

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/307/

```
data: [7,12,16,-1,32,64]
```

{{Edit:

updated example with startOnTick:false - http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/309/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but I want my yAxis label starting at 0. Should we perhaps use threshold , yAxis min to achieve this?

Comment: You can use `startOnTick: false` and `min:-1` for yAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/308/

Comment: Yes, startOnTick: false is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to go with this solution!